# Query con Join que funciona en Phpmyadmin no funciona en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo problemas para pasar un query tradicional a laravel. Funciona en phpmyadmin, pero al pasarla a Laravel, me regresa registros 0.

---

TABLA TALUMNOS

```
provincia (int)
dni (int)
nombre (varchar)
```

---

TABLA TESCUELAS:

```
 provincia (int)
 dni (int)
 anio (int)
```

---

Funciona OK en phpmyadmin:

```
select DISTINCT dni,nombre from talumnos inner join tescuelas on
tescuelas.provincia=talumnos.provincia where tescuelas.provincia=18
and tescuelas.anio<>0 AND tescuelas.dni=talumnos.dni
```

pero en Laravel no funciona (query1):

```
DB::table('talumnos')
->join('tescuelas', 'tescuelas.provincia','=','talumnos.provincia')
->select('dni','nombre')  
->where('tescuelas.provincia','=',18) 
->where('tescuelas.anio','<>',0) 
->where('tescuelas.dni','=','talumnos.dni') 
->distinct()
->get();
```

esto tampoco, con doble join (query 2):

```
DB::table('talumnos')
->join('tescuelas', function ($join) {
   $join->on('tescuelas.provincia','=','talumnos.provincia');
   ->orOn('tescuelas.dni','=','talumnos.dni');
   })
->select('tau_nmarc','gru_cgrup','gru_ngrup')
->where('tescuelas.provincia','=',18) 
->where('tescuelas.anio','<>',0) 
->where('tescuelas.dni','=','talumnos.dni') 
->distinct()
->get();
```

Mi acercamiento es en esta parte donde entiendo esta el problema:

```
->where('tescuelas.dni','=','talumnos.dni')
```

, pero ya intente variaciones haciendo dos joins (como el 2 código que puse), que sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: así tal cual la pones es tu consulta completa o le falta algo?, cuando la ejecutas te sale algún error?

Comment: la consulta esta completa, el resultado que tengo de ejecutar la primer query es: object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#223 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}

Comment: Creo que el tema esta aqui, porque en este where hago una consultade igualdad entre campos de las dos tablas:  ->where('tescuelas.dni','=','talumnos.dni')

Comment: al momento de hacer uso de table debería quedar tu consulta(la primera de ellas)  $data = DB::table('talumnos')
->join('tescuelas', 'tescuelas.provincia','=','talumnos.provincia')
->select('dni','nombre')  
->where('tescuelas.provincia','=',18) 
->where('tescuelas.anio','<>',0) 
->where('tescuelas.dni','=','talumnos.dni') 
->distinct()
->get();

Comment: puesto que no estas haciendo uso de los modelos si no de table, entonces debes invocar el facade DB en la parte superior y posterior usarlo como te lo pongo en el ejemplo

Comment: agregué en el código de ejemplo el facade, para que se entienda que el tema no es ese.

Comment: Es probable que en el `where` problemático que comentas debas usar [**`whereColumn`**, tal y como explica la documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses), o sea, algo así: `->whereColumn('tescuelas.dni', 'talumnos.dni')` **NÓTESE** que **no se usa el signo de igualdad**, pues `whereColumn` se ocupa de comparar si los valores de ambas columnas son iguales. Convendría también que uses *alias*  de tabla para cada cosa, por ejemplo en el `select` no los usas y habrá conflictos con columnas como `dni` que están en dos tablas.

Comment: Efectivamente @A. Cedano , funciono perfectamente.

Comment: Me alegro. Para una próxima conviene dar una explicación documentada sobre la solución del problema, indicando lo que recomienda la documentación y poniendo el enlace. Eso da mayor calidad a la respuesta y sirve como referencia para futuros usuarios. También, por deferencia se deja responder a quien ha dado con la solución del problema.

Comment: si entiendo, recien estoy aprendiendo como funciona stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente quedo asi, funcionando:

```
DB::table('talumnos')
->join('tescuelas', 'tescuelas.provincia','=','talumnos.provincia')
->select('dni','nombre')  
->where('tescuelas.provincia','=',18) 
->where('tescuelas.anio','<>',0) 
->whereColumn('tescuelas.dni','talumnos.dni') 
->distinct()
->get();
```